# Android, layout screen width

Tags: android, android-layout, screen

I'm in the process of making an application, but I've encountered an problem which is bugging me. I've created an application where one activity that fails to properly fit into smaller screens. I've checked on a Galaxy Nexus and on a SG2 and both of them looks perfect, but when it runs on a HTC Wildfire roughly 20% of the width is cut away (from the right). In the xml-file all layouts are defined as either wrap_content/fill_parent, all sizes are measured in dp and in the manifest i've set support screen for anyDensity, resizeable, and small,normal and large screens to true. The application is running on sdk version 7. The other thing is that when I use the emulator set up on the same values as the Wildfire it scales it down so it will fit, hence I have problems tracking down the problem. Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Comment: have you read http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I have, and what's bugging me is that I can't reproduce it in the emulator to test it myself.

Comment: You can reconfigure the emulator with a larger pixel density (dpi). This should cause your layout to scale up until you see the truncation problem. My guess is the emulator setting is 160dpi, but those devices have 240dpi.

Comment: Tried a couple of dpi's. Still not really getting it to work =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding a weight to each textview/edittext in question.